# Quaternions - Swapped axes and gimbal lock

Tags: opengl, math, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

I've been trying to get my head around quaternions in order to be able rotate objects in any ways, avoiding the popular gimbal lock problem.

I have certain sensor readings which are Euler angles and I have to convert them to quaternions.
Or rather will have, at the moment I'm only simulating the readings by feeding it some angles... At any rate, I HAVE to use Euler angles as my starting point in all calculations.

I've found a number of articles/guides covering this and all of them have failed to help me, effectively pointing out that the problem is between the keyboard and the chair...

Among the first guides I've found is this one http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation

I tried it, at the same time checking some other things to find out that it's one of the more popular ways of converting Euler to quaternions, GLM does it the same way as well.

Here's my implementation of this method:

```
float x, y, z, w,
c1 = cos(qDegreesToRadians(angle[0]) * 0.5f),
c2 = cos(qDegreesToRadians(angle[1]) * 0.5f),
c3 = cos(qDegreesToRadians(angle[2]) * 0.5f),
s1 = sin(qDegreesToRadians(angle[0]) * 0.5f),
s2 = sin(qDegreesToRadians(angle[1]) * 0.5f),
s3 = sin(qDegreesToRadians(angle[2]) * 0.5f);

x = s1 * c2 * c3 + c1 * s2 * s3;
y = c1 * s2 * c3 - s1 * c2 * s3;
z = s1 * s2 * c3 + c1 * c2 * s3;
w = c1 * c2 * c3 - s1 * s2 * s3;

QQuaternion quat(w, x, y, z);
```

The 'angle' var is an array containing Euler angles in the following format:

*0: Yaw, 1: Pitch, 2: Roll*

The result however wasn't something I'd expect at all.

[image: Result]

The black part is not rotated, the red part represents the resulting rotation of it. The rotation angle is 0 yaw, -90 pitch and 0 roll, which means the pitch is sideways. Why?

"Well, okay, let's just swap the axes, we'll see what's gonna happen" - I thought.
And at first glance it worked! I just swapped *x* with *y*.
Though the object was upside down, so I just negated one of the quaternions:

```
QQuaternion quat(w, -y, x, z);
```

Looks good so far, right?
[image: Result with swapped axes]

Let's try rotating it a bit...
Uh! Oh! It looks like when the pitch is either -90 or 90 the yaw and roll end up on the same axis... Gimbal lock.

Why are the axes swapped? Why does the gimbal lock occur even though I'm using quaternions? Is it because I'm using Euler angles on the input? If it is the problem then I don't think there's any way around it (considering the fact that I get my data in the form of Euler angles), is there?

Comment: you can simplify your math. Use quaternion construction from axisAngle and multiply 3 quaternions together

Comment: If all you are doing is converting Euler angles to Quaternions, then you will still suffer gimbal lock. Perhaps tell us a bit more about this sensor you are using? EG this problem becomes solvable if your sensor is gyroscope reporting Euler rates (not Euler angles).

Comment: Euler rates? Do you mean change in Euler angles? I can make it give me such data, just how exactly can it help me?

Comment: If your sensors give you body frame euler rates then you can integrate the quaternion derivative given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternion_.E2.86.94_angular_velocities  . this integration of euler rates lets you properly represent the attitude as a quaternion, avoiding gimbal lock. If this is applicable to you tell me and i will show you some example code.